# javascript scope privacy breaking?

Tags: javascript, scope

So I came across something very odd while working on a javascript project just now and here's a boiled down example of the situation I'm confused about:

```
function doSomething() {
    for(var d = 0;d < 10;d++) {
        var shouldBePrivate = 5;
    }

    for(var d = 0;d < 10;d++) {
        console.log(shouldBePrivate);
    }
}
```

When you call doSomething() the shouldBePrivate variable is accessible in the 2nd for loop.

Shouldn't that not be possible?

Answer (score 5):

All local variables in javascript have function scope and not the block scope (*atleast before `ECMAScript 2015`*). Which means that declared variables inside the function , available for whole function.

What you are referring is block scope. Unfortunately noblock scope in Javascript till `ECMA2015`. From  `ECMAScript 2015`, you can declare your variables with `let` which can be referred only with in the block and they die as soon as you come out of that block.

[MDN docs says (with examples)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

> Block Scoping Rules
>
> With **var**
>
> **Variables declared with var do not have block scope.** Variables introduced with a block are scoped to the containing function or script, and the effects of setting them persist beyond the block itself. In other words, block statements do not introduce a scope. Although "standalone" blocks are valid syntax, you do not want to use standalone blocks in JavaScript, because they don't do what you think they do, if you think they do anything like such blocks in C or Java. For

```
example:

var x = 1;
{
  var x = 2;
}
console.log(x); // logs 2
```

> This logs 2 because the var x statement within the block is in the same scope as the var x statement before the block. In C or Java, the equivalent code would have outputted 1.
>
> **With let and const**
>
> By contrast, identifiers declared with let and const do have block scope:

```
let x = 1;
{
  let x = 2;
}
console.log(x); // logs 1
The x = 2 is limited in scope to the block in which it was defined.
```

Comment: Oh wow derp. I had no idea javascript did that. Very interesting thanks so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You've stumbled upon something called hoisting. Because all variables are scoped to their containing function, `var` statements are internally moved to the top of the function.

That means that the interpreter will actually be running this code:

```
function doSomething() {
    var shouldBePrivate;
    var d;
    for(d = 0;d < 10;d++) {
        shouldBePrivate = 5;
    }

    for(d = 0;d < 10;d++) {
        // now it's easy to see why this works
        console.log(shouldBePrivate);
    }
}
```

As of ES2015, you can use the `let` keyword instead of `var` which is lexically scoped - i.e. scoped within blocks, meaning that `let shouldBePrivate = 5;` will not exist outside the first loop.

```
function doSomething() {
    for(let d = 0;d < 10;d++) {
        let shouldBePrivate = 5;
    }

    for(let d = 0;d < 10;d++) {
        // Reference Error for shouldBePrivate 
        console.log(shouldBePrivate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeeze, that's interesting I had no idea. Thanks for the info!